# macOS - Error code 100035 while copying files or upload files

Tags: macos, finder

I am using macOS Ventura 13.0.1.

So far, I’ve had no problem, but suddenly I can't copy/upload the files to another PC via LAN or onto any websites via web browser.

The error dialog in the attached screenshot was what I get about 20 minutes after since the copy had been started. It stuck in the zero bytes and finally get this error.

I tried to use the online email via browser or some file transfer sites (WeTransfer), but all have failed.

How can I fix it?

P.S. My Finder keeps crashing. Not sure whether it's related to this issue.

[image]

Comment: @Giacomo1968 yes, doesn't work.

Comment: If the Finder keeps crashing, there's some deeper problem we can't diagnose from where we sit.

Comment: @IconDaemon is correct.  Before figuring out why you can’t transfer files, you need to solve the more “global” problem of Finder’s instability. Once you solve that, you can focus on the file x-fer issue, if it still exists.

Comment: thanks for your reply. Is there any way to install the os again but keep the current apps and user data? @IconDaemon

Comment: thanks for your reply. Is there any way to install the os again but keep the current apps and user data? @Allan

Comment: Yes. You can reinstall macOS without affecting your user data and installed apps. Make a backup first!  Follow the steps found in this [Apple Support Page](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/use-macos-recovery-on-an-intel-based-mac-mchl338cf9a8/mac) if you have an Intel based Mac. [This guide](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/macos-recovery-a-mac-apple-silicon-mchl82829c17/mac) should be used if you have an Apple Silicon Mac.